# C++ exceptions binary compatibility

Tags: c++, exception, binary-compatibility

my project uses 2 different C++ compilers, g++ and nvcc (cuda compiler).
I have noticed exception thrown from nvcc object files are not caught in g++ object files.

are C++ exceptions supposed to be binary compatible in the same machine?
what can cause such behavior?

```
try { kernel_= new cuda:: Kernel(); }
catch (...) { kernel_= NULL; }

// nvcc object
cuda:: Kernel:: Kernel () {
  ...
  if (! impl_) throw;
}
```

everything else seems to work (C++ objects, operators).  To be honest I do not know exceptions very well so maybe there is mistake in the code above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

nvcc is a wrapper around a normal c++ compiler, and is basically a preprocessor to convert the cuda syntax into something compilable. You can see what compiler it uses with the `--verbose` flag.

For instance on my machine compiling

```
// test.cpp
int main(){return 0;}
```

with `nvcc -v` gives

```
#$ _SPACE_= 
#$ _MODE_=DEVICE
#$ _HERE_=/usr/local/cuda/bin
#$ _THERE_=/usr/local/cuda/bin
#$ TOP=/usr/local/cuda/bin/..
#$ PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin/../open64/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin/../bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/Users/me/bin:/usr/local/aspell/bin:/usr/local/noweb:/usr/local/icon/bin:/usr/local/dmd/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sed/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
#$ INCLUDES="-I/usr/local/cuda/bin/../include"  
#$ LIBRARIES=  "-L/usr/local/cuda/bin/../lib" -lcudart
#$ CUDAFE_FLAGS=
#$ OPENCC_FLAGS=
#$ PTXAS_FLAGS=
#$ gcc -c -x c++ "-I/usr/local/cuda/bin/../include"   -I. -m32 -malign-double -o "/tmp/tmpxft_000010af_00000000-1_test.o" "test.cpp" 
#$ g++ -m32 -malign-double -o "a.out" "/tmp/tmpxft_000010af_00000000-1_test.o"   "-L/usr/local/cuda/bin/../lib" -lcudart
```

Using the same compiler/flags as listed here should give you binary compatibility

Answer (score 8):

Sorry to give you two "no" answers in a single night, but "No", C++ exceptions (or classes for that matter) have no standard binary layout. Attempting to use C++ classes/exceptions between two differing compilers breaks the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

You can work around this by only allowing a C API between the object files (because C *has* a standard ABI - Application Binary Interface), or you can compile all your code with one compiler or the other. I'm not sure if the last bit is possible with NVCC, however.

In response to question edit: **everything else seems to work (C++ objects, operators)**: There are lots of things that *seem* to work in the vast majority of cases. That does not mean they do not invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: I find it rather surprising that most things seem to work. Usually, different compilers purposely have different name mangling schemes, so that you can avoid these problems early, namely at compile time or link time.

Comment: @Ken: This is true; but not so with exception handling -- namely, because this is one of the places where compilers differ quite a bit. MSVC++, for example, builds its exception support on top of NT's SEH, while GCC uses some form of table based implementation.

Comment: what I meant was that I'm surprised most stuff seems to work, because if two different compilers implement different ABIs in some way (no matter how subtle), then I would expect them to purposely have different name-mangling schemes, so that you couldn't possibly make the mistake of combining binaries from two different compilers. See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/compiler-dependencies.html#faq-38.9

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard doesn't specify the binary form of anything, let alone exceptions.  There's no reason you should expect this to work.